# Magento search is not working for specific sku values

Tags: magento-enterprise, configurable-product, catalogsearch

I am facing a weird issue in magento enterprise version 1.12.0.2. I have created a configurable product with SKU "CVR" but when I search in top search bar, I get no result for this SKU.
If I change the SKU value to something else like "5656" or "ABCD", it gives me the product in search.
I have reindexed every time and flushed all cache after I make any change to product even if all cache are disabled. Still I am not able to search using the SKU value "CVR". Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the default MySQL full text function is set to 4 characters, which means you can only search words that have 4 or more characters, which is why "5656" and "ABCD" work.

You can decrease this to 3 characters, which will allow you to search on "CVR" or something.

To achieve this, you have to change the `ft_min_word_len` option in your MySQL settings:

```
ft_min_word_len=3
```

More info on how to achieve this can be found in the MySQL docs:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

Comment: Hi Maikel, I found that you are right about query length. But there is also a product with SKU "2558" and it is also not appearing in search results. Can there be any other issue?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned that should work.. Have you reindexed your tables? And can you update your question with the query you perform?